# Renaming the headers of every data frame in a list

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, names

I have a list containing a number of data frames, all with the same number of columns.

E.g, for a list `df_list` with two data frames, `df1` and `df2`:

```
>df_list

df1
a    b    c
1    1    1
2    2    2
3    3    3

df2
a    b    c
3    2    1
3    2    1
3    2    1
```

I want to rename the headers of every data frame to `new_headings <- c("A", "B", "C")`.

I constructed a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(list)) {
     names(list[[i]]) <- new_headings
}
```

However, this doesn't work. The headings remain as they were. If I do it individually instead of in a loop, it works fine, however, e.g., `names(list[[1]]) <- new_headings` changes the headings appropriately.

My actual list is very long with many data frames. Can anyone explain why this isn't working or what other approach I can use? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` with `setNames`

```
df_listNew <- Map(setNames, df_list, list(new_headings))
```

---

Or using `lapply`

```
lapply(df_list, setNames, new_headings)
#$df1
#  A B C
#1 1 1 1
#2 2 2 2
#3 3 3 3

#$df2
#  A B C
#1 3 2 1
#2 3 2 1
#3 3 2 1
```

#### data

```
df_list <- list(df1 = structure(list(a = 1:3, b = 1:3, c = 1:3), 
       class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), df2 = structure(list(a = c(3, 3, 3), b = c(2, 2, 2), c = c(1, 
1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two for loops

```
a<-c(1,2,3)
b<-c(1,2,3)
c<-c(1,2,3)
df1<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
a<-c(3,2,1)
b<-c(3,2,1)
c<-c(3,2,1)
df2<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))

df_list<-list(df1,df2)

new_headings <- c("A", "B", "C")   

for (i in 1:length(df_list)) {
  for (j in 1:length(df_list[[i]])) {
    colnames(df_list[[i]])[j] <- new_headings[j]
  }
}

df_list
```